# Play different mp3 file with the same name on each page refresh

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, mp3

I have a list of files of mp3 files:

```
http://server.com/7fb77afc17f7.mp3 
http://server.com/9fc048752087.mp3  
http://server.com/2k4487f62227.mp3
```

And I need that each time I open:

```
http://server.com/music.mp3
```

It plays a random fils that I have. What is the best way to do this?

I thinking about nginx rewrites, maybe with a help of php.

something like this will work?

```
location / {
     rewrite 2k4487f62227.mp3 /music.mp3 break;
     rewrite 9fc048752087.mp3 /music.mp3 break;
 }
```

Comment: Put them into an array and take a random element I guess ?! Google: 1. `PHP Arrays` 2. `PHP array_rand()` <- Start reading :) (<- If you get stuck show where you are with your code)

Comment: @Rizier123 yes i can, but i need the same final name at the end. Maybe i need just rewrite those files with nginx

Comment: *same final name* I thought you want a random file?

Comment: @Rizier123 random file with the same end name (music.mp3)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not require the configuration to be in nginx, you can create a php only solution:

1 - List mp3 files in folder

Just in case someone is looking for a copy-paste / effortless solution as mentioned in the comments to this answer, here is a sample for the first part (minus the filter for the extension):

```
static function getFiles($dir, $includeFolders = true) {
    if (substr($dir, -1) != "/") $dir = "{$dir}/";
    $files = array();
    if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if (($file != ".") && ($file != "..") && ($includeFolders || !is_dir($dir.$file))) {
                $files[] = $file;
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    return $files;
}
```

2 - use array_rand to return one of the files

3 - play the file

Comment: And that didn't fit into a comment? *Err.* yes it does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578444/play-different-mp3-file-on-each-page-refresh#comment49226993_30578444

Comment: @Rizier123 and why exactly should it be in a comment instead of an answer? Does this not fit as an answer?

Comment: How should this be useful as an answer for everyone, which comes by this question and don't know how to code that and are looking for a solution here.

Comment: @Rizier123 I am sorry but I don't agree with you. I feel that answers should teach people how to fish, and not put a fish on their plate. if they don't know how to code, searching for each of the points will teach them something.